# Dagger 2, Cicerone, Kotlin - inject problem

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2

This code works perfectly in Java, but has an undefined problem in Kotlin

**Problem**:

> error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] ru.terrakok.cicerone.Router cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
>       public abstract void inject(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>
> ru.terrakok.cicerone.Router is injected at
>             com.setname.dagger2ciceronelearning.presentation.main.MainActivity.mRouter
>
> com.setname.dagger2ciceronelearning.presentation.main.MainActivity is injected at
>             com.setname.dagger2ciceronelearning.di.AppComponent.inject(com.setname.dagger2ciceronelearning.presentation.main.MainActivity)

**AppComponent**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(NavigationModule::class))
interface AppComponent {

    fun inject(mainActivity: MainActivity)
    fun inject(fragmentOne: FragmentOne)
    fun inject(fragmentTwo: FragmentTwo)

}
```

**NavigationModule**

```
@Module
class NavigationModule {

    private val firstLevelNavigation: Cicerone<Router> = Cicerone.create()
    private val secondLevelNavigation: Cicerone<Router> = Cicerone.create()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named(Navigation.ROUTER_FIRST_LEVEL)
    fun provideFirstLevelRouter(): Router = firstLevelNavigation.router

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named(Navigation.ROUTER_SECOND_LEVEL)
    fun provideSecondLevelRouter(): Router = secondLevelNavigation.router

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named(Navigation.NAV_HOLDER_FIRST_LEVEL)
    fun provideFirstLevelNavigatorHolder(): NavigatorHolder = firstLevelNavigation.navigatorHolder


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named(Navigation.NAV_HOLDER_SECOND_LEVEL)
    fun provideSecondLevelNavigationHolder(): NavigatorHolder = secondLevelNavigation.navigatorHolder

}
```

**LearingApp**

```
class LearningApp : Application() {

    companion object {

        lateinit var appComponent: AppComponent

    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent
            .builder()
            .build()
    }

}
```

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    @Named(Navigation.ROUTER_FIRST_LEVEL)
    lateinit var mRouter: Router

    @Inject
    @Named(Navigation.NAV_HOLDER_FIRST_LEVEL)
    lateinit var mNavigatorHolder: NavigatorHolder

    private lateinit var mNavigator:Navigator

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        LearningApp.appComponent.inject(this)

        mNavigator = SupportAppNavigator(this, R.id.main_container)

        mRouter.newRootScreen(Screens.FragmentOneScreen())

    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        mNavigatorHolder.setNavigator(mNavigator)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        mNavigatorHolder.removeNavigator()
        super.onPause()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a very wise man said once: `You need to target the annotation at the field by using @field:Named.`

Comment: But a few years later, the same wise man said: «‎I was half right. You need to target the annotation at the field by using @field:Named. But that didn't solve his problem.»‎

Comment: But a few second after he said:«‎No, it will solve his problem.»‎

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use custom qualifiers:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention
annotation class RouterFirstLevel
```

then your module:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
@RouterFirstLevel
fun provideFirstLevelRouter(): Router = firstLevelNavigation.router
```

and activity:

```
@Inject
@RouterFirstLevel
lateinit var mRouter: Router
```

P.S. I agree with jbarat though, field in annotation should have helped, try to use string instead of string constants, maybe some type mismatch